# Unable find query execution place in spring batch

Tags: spring, batch-processing

Hi if this question is too primary please ignore this. I am currently analyzing a code snippet and I stuck in this place,

```
@Override
public List<BaseLineInfoEntity> findAllBaseLineInfo() {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT baseline FROM BaseLineInfoEntity baseline",
            BaseLineInfoEntity.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

This method works perfectly and giving back the results but I coudn't understand how this query is executed and got the data. If someone can understand what's happening here please guide me through it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look and read more here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_jpql.htm

The example is very similar to what you have here.

Comment: I have look in to that already they have given a table in theirs but in my case I can't even find where the table or db is in. I want to know from where data comes in my project.

Comment: I am not sure what is in your example, but it might be that when you connect to url, username, pass...etc. so establish the connection you actually already have that one available. Normally you have to first create your own database (or have it) and then connect to it!